# I need to detect a swipe gesture on my tableView that is within a page control, how can I do this?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

Pretty straight forward, I just can't get it to work. What can I do to swipe to delete on my tableView that is within a page control?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to remove my original answer regarding the proper UITableViewDataSource methods.

This sounds like a potentially complicated user interface (i.e. if users are expecting swipes to turn a page but if they mis-touch and hit the table view cell just right, they'll get the "delete" button). I'd suggest re-thinking what you are doing.

In any event, to get to the finish line on your app *might* be to subclass UIPageControl, detect when swipes are happening in the content region and pass that swipe message along to the table view.  I suspect you can't just do `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` on the page control's content view.

F.Y.I.: you should also probably delete the identical & duplicate question you posted a number of hours before the question I'm attempting to answer ( [How can I capture a sideways swipe gesture for a tableView that is inside of a pageControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147955/how-can-i-capture-a-sideways-swipe-gesture-for-a-tableview-that-is-inside-of-a-p) )

Comment: I do have those methods in place, the only problem is that the touch isn't caught by the tableView, but the scrollView intercepts it and switches the page control.